# Install Ghost Blog

Tags: linux, ghost-blog

I've been trying to get Ghost.io installed on my web server for quite sometime. I have a VPS with Centos 6 and Cpanel.

Today I found a script at http://www.allaboutghost.com/one-click-ghost-install-script/ that said you could just enter a command into your ssh terminal and have it all installed for you.

**Command**

```
wget -O - https://raw.github.com/howtoinstallghost/installghost.sh/master/installGhost.sh | sudo bash
```

I did this and it appears to have worked, I didn't get any errors but now I am not able to find the install in either FileZilla or by using my web browser. The website says that it installs in the `/var/www/ghost/` directory but I can't find that. If I use `cd /var/www/ghost/` in the ssh it takes me right to it and even lets me edit the `config.example.js` file.

If I direct my browser to `www.mydomain.com:80` since the site says it installs on port 80 it just takes me back to my home page.

What am I missing and what do I need to do?

As Per the comments, I did follow the instructions on the github page. Now All I get when I visit `mydomainname.com/ghost/`

[image]

Comment: That script is comically bad. Don't use it. Follow the installation instructions on the real Ghost project web site: https://github.com/tryghost/Ghost

Comment: `wget -O - https://yadda.yadda | sudo bash` You are downloading a file from the Internet and feeding it directly into a root shell? Do you understand how insecure this is?

Answer (score 0):

Ghost is installed really easy. You'd better don't use 3rd party scripts for that as it might really vary from system to system. All you need is to get Node.js installed and then follow instruction for example from here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-ghost-on-ubuntu-16-04. They are very detailed and must work for Centos as well.

Most common errors are:
- Not configuring a reverse proxy (nginx or apache) to link to your ghost install on port 2368. Here is an example for Nginx:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name your_domain_or_ip_address;
    location / {
    proxy_set_header HOST $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:2368;
    }
}
```

If you now see default home page it means some web server is already running and intercept all the requests and parks them to a default location (e.g. /var/www)
- If you want Ghost to be the one and the only web server on your VPS, you have to remove or shut down currently installed web server and try to configure ghost to answer on port 80 like this:

```
server: {
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: '80'
}
```

I didn't test it but has to work. This kind of install is not recommended and insecure. I suppose you can configure reverse proxy from Cpanel, but not sure.

The best and easiest way to set up Ghost is using SSH.

Hope it helps. For any further help, you have to provide more details and possibly logs and configs. Most of the possible errors you'll catch when installing or starting your blog with npm

`sudo npm install --production`
`sudo npm start --production`

Good luck with your deployment.

Answer (score -2):

Hey you don't need to do that much you can just launch ghost from digitalpress for free...
Know how to host ghost blog for free out here : https://treanches.digitalpress.blog/hosting-ghost-blog/
You can think this as self promotion but this article is so much understanding you won't regret reading it

Comment: hello @anand The site is not functionning properly. Please note that link-only answers are discouraged on this site.